# Firebase web sign out doesn't send any XHR

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When setting up a simple form - 2 buttons with 2 functions to test firebase's auth, i have a problem with sign out.

The sign in function works perfect.
However, sign out doesn't send any XHR. Nothing, nada. No errors. 
But the promise resolves. 
The console logs 'Signed Out'.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
    function signIn() {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('email@email.com', 'password')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Logged in')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage)
            });
    }

    function signOut() {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            console.log('Signed out!')
        }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Signing out just involves "forgetting" the refresh token that's used to keep the user signed in persistently over time.  The server doesn't need to be notified that this happened.